# How to change lookup table parameter by inport value in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, lookup-tables

I want to make a lookup table sub-system in MATLAB Simulink.

A mask is made to allow user to input `x1 ~ x4`.

I want the value of `H` to be tunable by input (`H` comes from upper stream). Is it possible in Simulink? If so, how to make the subsys?

**Lookup table:**
[image: lookup table]]

**subsys1:**
[image: subsys1]]

**subsys2:**
[image: subsys2]]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the "look up table dynamic" block, it has inputs for the table data. This allows you to have a constant block x and an input signal h. Both are subtracted and fed into the lut block.

Comment: I want to plot the curve on the block with parameter H which comes from input port, how can I make that? Thanks a lot

Comment: I am not sure how to understand your comment. Does the calculation itself work with the dynamic block and your remaining question is how to change the block icon?

Comment: sorry for making you confused. the "kookup table dynamic" works well. The 1st question has been solved by your answer and thank you very much. Now I want to build block mask for this subsystem, I want to plot the lookup data curve as the icon, I don't know how to get the value H which comes from an inport. (I'm not a native English speaker, forgive my poor English :-P)

Comment: The basics are explained here: https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/create-mask-icon.html This explains how you can use x1 to x4 and draw a plot. Do you also want to use your input signal H which potentially changes during simulation, thus have a mask icon which changes during simulation? If this is your goal, I would suggest a new question. I have seen such blocks but I don't know how they are created.

Comment: plotting with H is my goal. so it looks like that i need to start a new question. Thank you again and happy new year~

Comment: I find a way to modify the block icon by detecting the value change and command `set_param(blk, 'MaskDisplay', 'plot (xxxx)')`.